# Ошибка в php Fatal error:

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php

    $title='Post';
    $back="index.php";
    $logotext= "Post";
    $home= "../index.php";
    require "header.php";


    function get_post_by_id($id) {          //Здесь я создал функцию которая получает статью по ее id.
    global $db;
    $posts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $id");
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    return $post;
    }
    }
?>

<?php 
    $post = get_post_by_id($_GET['id']);
?>
```

И он выдает ошибку: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\OSPanel\domains\rus\fullPost.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\rus\fullPost.php(20): get_post_by_id(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\rus\fullPost.php on line 12

12 строкой является строка:
`$posts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $id");`

Помогите пажалуйста...
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Откуда берётся объект $db? Скорее всего, он пуст

Comment: в метод get_post_by_id в место $id вы отправили null по этому это ошибка:
 function get_post_by_id($id = 0 ) {       
    global $db;
    $posts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id =" .$id);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    return $post;
    }
    }

Comment: Переменная $db берется от другого файла и определена как глобальная
 $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
 $username = "root";
 $password= "";
 $dbname = "historylifensk";
 
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

Comment: @HistoryLifeNSK а этот файл подключается ли? Ошибка означает, что никакого `$db` на момент вызова `query`  нет.

Comment: Все, разобрался, всем огромное спасибо что не оставили без внимания)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка означает, что вы не передаете в функцию get_post_by_id параметр $id (передается NULL), также глобальная переменная $db у вас не была объявлена ранее, соответственно, она также является NULL.

Вам нужно провести отладку кода в тех местах, где происходит объявление $db, а также вызов функции get_post_by_id и передача параметра $id на предмет ошибок. Вероятно, что у вас есть ошибка при подключении зависимых файлов, в результате которой, участок кода, где происходит объявление, на самом деле не подключается, вызывая подобные ошибки.